# Unable to wait while iterating through webdriver dropdown

Tags: python, selenium

I need assistance with web driver using python. I am trying to iterate through a dropdown list using a wait. A selected dropdown item automatically updates page so webdriverwait is needed to give the page time to update. Need to iterate through a dropdown of 10 items and wait between each item. Any examples on how this is done?

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice to explain why you think "iterating through a dropdown list" is different from iterating through an ordinary list.  Also your title says that you are "unable" to do this, which would imply that you tried something and it didn't work.  Please tell us what that was.

Comment: Could you provide atleast some scenario that's why we could try it and give you solution... and also need to share why you are unable with your code as well as HTML and exception..thanks

Comment: I am trying to navigate through the element in the dropdown menu of my website using web driver for testing purposes. Currently I am able to iterate through the items but I need to WAIT for page to load based on selected item before moving to next item in menu.

Answer (score 0):

General pattern of what you want to do could be:

1. Create a list of pairs `item to select, condition to wait for after selection`
2. Loop on this list

I am not very much of a python developer, so take the code below as pseudo-code with python flavour:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# First item in tuple is the value of select, 
# Second is the value to wait for after selecting the item
verify_list = [('item1', '//xpath1'),('item2', '//xpath2'),...]

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for item,condition in verify_list:

    # Get select itself (since page refreshes, you may need to do it after each select)
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath"))

    # Select the value (for example by visible text)
    select.select_by_visible_text(item)

    # Wait for condition. For example presence of the element
    # try/catch can be added here, if you want to run all options, 
    # even if one of them fails.
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, condition))
```